# How to use If else condition in python to check existence of files?

Tags: python

I am new to python and trying to run the following code to get the files in the specified format on the current path using the if-else statement.

```
from pathlib import Path

path=Path()
for file in path.glob('*.txt'):
    if file.exists():
        print(file)
    else:
        print("No items match your search")
```

It works for the if condition, by printing all the files that match the given file format. But not to the else condition. My intention is to print as "No items match your search" if a file in the specified format does not exist.
Can anyone help to make this code run properly?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: if file.endswith?

Comment: `glob` already iterates over all existing files, why do you want to check again if they exist?

Comment: you should "walk" through the path and check what kind of extension you have with given file. In your solution, well... lets say you "take" list of txt files, then check if those files are files and execute code. 'else' will be never executed. Use os.walk()

Answer (score 3):

```
for file in path.glob('*.txt')
```

Your `for` loop runs for every file that `glob` finds, hence

```
for file in path.glob('*.txt'):
    if file.exists():
```

is rather pointless, because `file` must exist, otherwise `glob` would not have reported it. What you want is to check if glob has returned any files:

```
filelist = list(path.glob('*.txt'))
if len(filelist) == 0:
    print("No items match your search")
for file in filelist:
    print(file)
```

Comment: Thank you! @FlyingTeller but It's getting this error  ```TypeError:object of type 'generator' has no len()```

Comment: @UpaniK that's because the `glob` returns a generator, it has to be turned into a list first, check out my answer

Comment: oh! Okay! Thank you so much for the clear explanation.

Comment: @agentsmith @OferSadan thank you for pointing it out, forgot the `list()`

Answer (score 3):

If files are found using `path.glob('*.txt')` then they necessarily exist, so there's no reason why `if file.exists()` will ever evaluate to `False`

The correct way to check if no files were found is to check the length of results:

```
from pathlib import Path

path=Path()
result = list(path.glob('*.txt'))
if len(result) == 0:
    print('No items match your search')
else:
    print('Found items that match your search: ', result)
```

Comment: "so there's no reason why if file.exists() will ever evaluate to False". Unless some other program deletes the file in the split second between the glob calculation and the .exists check (race condition). But if this is a real problem, then more thinking is needed specific to the exact requirements.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel this is true

Comment: Playing devil's advocate: it's possible that one or more of the files may get deleted by another process in the middle of the for loop, especially if the for loop contains operations that take a long time.

Comment: @JackTaylor that's exactly what Karl said, which is correct, but it appears like the objective here is just to list/print the results, so that can always change anyway

Comment: Yep, I started writing my comment before Karl posted; sorry for the duplication!

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it:

```
from pathlib import Path

cwd = Path()
files = list(cwd.glob('*.txt'))
if files:
    for file in files:
        print(file)
else:
    print("No items match your search")
```

Similarly to Ofer, I would transform the [generator function](https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/) returned by Path.glob() into a list, so that you can check if it contains any items or not. Generator functions by themselves always evaluate to True, and you can only find out if they contain any items by calling them with `next()` or with a for loop.

In Python, the empty list evaluates to False, so you can get away with just `if files:` in the condition part of the if statement. Then I would omit the `if file.exists():` check, because all files found by Path.glob() will exist at the time it is run. The rest of the logic shouldn't contain any surprises.

Alternatively, if your script might match a lot of files, and you want to avoid the overhead of loading all the file objects into memory at once in your list of results, then you can use a flag variable.

```
cwd = Path()
found = False
for file in cwd.glob('*.txt'):
    print(file)
    found = True
if not found:
    print("No items match your search")
```